# If you don't use your permanent unlock, will you have two if you prestige again?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When you prestige you get a permanent unlock.  If you do it again, without using that first one, will you then have two?  With this thread of logic, can you essentially save them up?

It would be pretty useless to save them, except I play on an account with my brother and I let him choose what to unlock since he plays more, so I don't want to waste one if you don't get to keep it.

Comment: Just be careful when you get close to master prestige, which is what I just hit. Please see my answer for more details about what happened for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you are referring to Prestige Unlock tokens since you are talking about gear.

> When a player Prestiges, they earn a Prestige Unlock Token that permanently unlocks any one item

I haven't personally made it to 2nd prestige, but I'd be confident that you can bank these if you want, since they are token format and in the previous game you could bank the tokens for later use (and I did so personally).

Answer (score 1):

You get to keep all of them so they accumulate, so if you prestige and then prestige again then you will end up having 2, if you prestige 2 more times then you will have 4, and so on. I'm 10th prestige and have waited for awhile to use them and they were all still there to permanently unlock guns, perks, or scorestreaks. If you have questions about my answer then feel free to ask away and I'll be happy to clarify. There should be no worry about prestiging over and over again though.

**EDIT**: I just hit master prestige and wanted to mention that if you don't have 10 classes by the time that you hit master prestige you'll get locked out. I'm stuck with 9 classes because I didn't spend my tokens on extra classes. It's not a big deal, but I thought it was worth mentioning for all the people that really wanted that 10th class.

Happy Gaming!